# Getting the exact diff from the Ienumerable.except

Tags: c#, linq

I am using LINQ ENumerable.except to get the diff out of two lists of MyType. When I find a diff, I need to retrieve what was different in both base and compare list for the corresponding diff item. LIke,

I have two lists to compare

```
Base:
Name="1",Type="a",Switch="384347324372432"
Name="1",Type="b",Switch="43432432423"
Name="2",Type="q",Switch="4324324234"

Compare List:
Name="1",Type="a",Switch="aAAAA384347324372432"
Name="1",Type="c",Switch="23432432"
Name="2",Type="q",Switch="3423432423432"
Name="2",Type="q",Switch="4324324234"
```

Ouuput would be

```
  Found diff.
  Base: 
  Name="1",Type="a",Switch="384347324372432"
  Corresponding compare value:
  Name="1",Type="a",Switch="aAAAA384347324372432"

  etc...
```

I have written my own class object, say MyType for storing these as items properties

Defined a custom comparer like

```
class mycomparer: System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<MyType>
{

    public mycomparer() {}

    public bool Equals(MyType type1, MyType type2)
    {

        return ( (type1.Name.ToLower() == type2.Name.ToLower()) && (type1.Type.ToLower() ==         type2.Type.ToLower()) (type1.Switch.ToLower() == type2.Switch.ToLower())

    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyType type)
    {

        return string.concat(type.Name, type.Type, type.Switch).ToLower().GetHashCode();

    }

}
```

In my code, I use

```
MyComparer mine = new MyComparer();
IEnumerable<MyType> diff = baseList.Except(compareList,mine);
```

I get the diff correctly. But for the values that are different in baselist, I want to know what the corresponding value in comparelist was.

I do

```
foreach(Mytype type in diff)
{
     Console.writeline(type.Name+type.Type+type.Switch);
}
```

How to I get the corresponding values for compare list.

I tried something like,

```
IEnumerable<MyType> compareValue = Comparelist.Where(tempFile => tempFile.Name.ToLower() ==     type.Name.ToLower() && tempFile.Type.ToLower() == process.Type.ToLower()
```

(Basically, switch is what could be different here mostly)

But the problem is, in some cases, there may be duplicate Name="" Type="", so the above where retrieves more than one item, so the corresponding comparelist value would be different.

I tried writing the diff values from Equal methods, but didnt work for me.

UPdate:

In the case when duplicate name and type are found and switch has a mismatch, I think diff is calculated correctly, but when the output is written to console, incorrect diff value is written, here is the sample.

```
   Base:
   Name="2",Type="q",Switch="4324324234"
   Name="2",Type="q",Switch="3423432423432"

   Compare List:
   Name="2",Type="q",Switch="4324324234"
   Name="2",Type="q",Switch="3423432423432dwqdwqdwqdqwdwdq"

   base.except(compare) (as used in my sample code or Moho's solution) gets the diff correctly,
```

but with 
      diffSwitches.ToList().ForEach

I will get something like

```
      base:  Name="2",Type="q",Switch="3423432423432"
      Compare:    Name="2",Type="q",Switch="4324324234"
```

You see that is not the corresponding mismatch. Infact Switch="4324324234" is correctly matched. This is the problem I see.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
baseList.Except( compareList, mine ).Union( compareList.Except( baseList.Except, mine ) )
```

Edit after new requirements:

```
        var baseList = new List<MyType>()
        {
            new MyType() { Name="1",Type="a",Switch="384347324372432" },
            new MyType() { Name="1",Type="b",Switch="43432432423" },
            new MyType() { Name="2",Type="q",Switch="4324324234" }
        };

        var compareList = new List<MyType>()
        {
            new MyType() { Name="1",Type="a",Switch="aAAAA384347324372432" },
            new MyType() { Name="1",Type="c",Switch="23432432" },
            new MyType() { Name="2",Type="q",Switch="3423432423432" },
            new MyType() { Name="2",Type="q",Switch="4324324234" }
        };

        // matched Name/Type w/ different Switch
        var diffSwitches = baseList.Join( compareList, 
            bl => new { bl.Name, bl.Type }, 
            cl => new { cl.Name, cl.Type }, 
            ( bl, cl ) => new { 
                baseItem = bl, 
                compareItem = cl } )
            .Where( o => o.baseItem.Switch != o.compareItem.Switch );

        diffSwitches.ToList().ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}: {2}; {3}", i.baseItem.Name, i.baseItem.Type, i.baseItem.Switch, i.compareItem.Switch));
```

Comment: This will list all the diffs in the two lists, but I still cant tell what the corresponding mismatches are.

Comment: What would be the return time of the join operation? I am getting runtime errors about unable to cast to a type. I also updated b1 => new {} to something like b1=> new Mytype(name,type).

Comment: Here is the error. Unable to cast object of type 'WhereEnumerableIterator`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`2
[MyType,MyType]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyType]'.

Comment: the return type is an anonymous type with baseItem and compareItem properties

Comment: Thank you. This seems to have simplied my code correctly, but it looks like I am running into the same problem that made me writ this post. When there are more than one name= and type=. Please see the end of post.

Comment: you haven't specified sufficient requirements for that case - what do you want to happen if a match is found but other duplicate-keyed mismatches are also found?

Comment: Actually I just want them as diff. I have updated them at the end of my question. Problem is with when we iterate our i and print it, I get a different value

Answer (score 1):

Let both list be named `list` and `list2`. This is a solution:

```
var common = list1.Intersect(list2, new mycomparer());
var result = list1.Concat(list2)
                  .Except(common, new mycomparer())
                  .GroupBy (x => new { x.Name, x.Type } );
```

So both lists are concatenated, then the elements common in both lists are removed, and finally the remaining items are grouped by `Name` and `Type`.

Maybe useful to add that if `MyType` is a `struct`, you don't need the comparer, because structs are equal when their values are equal.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I am looking for. I need the correseponding diff between the two lists.

Comment: This concept of "correseponding diff" is still confusing. It's a _contradictio in terminis_. Either elements are different _or_ they correspond. You seem to define correspondence by having name and type in common. Is my query conceptually wrong or is it just the shape of the output that doesn't fit the bill?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the results you want with a slight change to your comparer:

```
    class mycomparer : System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<Item>
    {

        bool customcomparer = false;
        public mycomparer(bool custom = false) 
        {
            customcomparer = custom;
        }


        public bool Equals(Item type1, Item type2)
        {

            return GetHashCode(type1) == GetHashCode(type2);
        }
        public int GetHashCode(Item type)
        {
            if (customcomparer)
                return string.Concat(type.Name, type.Type).ToLower().GetHashCode();
            return string.Concat(type.Name, type.Type, type.Switch).ToLower().GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

And your class set up like this:

```
    public class MyType
    {
        public String Name, Type, Switch;
        public MyType()
        {

        }
        public MyType(string _name, string _type, string _switch)
        {
            Name = _name;
            Type = _type;
            Switch = _switch;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Name = " + this.Name + ",Type = " + this.Type + ",Switch = " + this.Switch;
        }

    }
```

And a second IEnumerable like this:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mycomparer mine = new mycomparer();
        mycomparer mine2 = new mycomparer(true);
        IEnumerable<MyType> diff = baseList.Except(compareList, mine);
        IEnumerable<MyType> diff2 = compareList.Intersect(diff, mine2);
        string message = "Base:\n";
        foreach (MyType item in diff)
        {

            message += item.ToString() + "\n";
        }
        message += "Corresponding compare value:\n";
        foreach (MyType item in diff2)
        {
            message += item.ToString() + "\n";
        }
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
```

I noticed `diff` returns 2 items Name 1 Type a and Name 1 Type b.  This is from your original code so I left it like that.

Comment: Problem is that I want the corresponding entries written together. I want to be able to compare them in my logs.